# sh, Ошибка File name too long

Tags: bash, sh

Недавно столкнулся с забавной ошибкой sh. Называется "File name too long".

Есть скрипт который должен переместить определенные файлы из одной директории в другую. Для примера написал этот скрипт, в настоящем все дело похожее.

Возьмем это

```
for iface in $(ls "/data/dalvik-cache" ); do
    mkdir "/cache/dalvikcache/$iface"
done
```

В директории /data/dalvik-cache хранятся такие длинные файлы как

`system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex
system@framework@javax.obex.jar@classes.dex`

На выводе я получаю, слижком длинный вывод, лог вот

```
system@framework@monkey.jar@classes.dex
system@framework@pm.jar@classes.dex
system@framework@services.jar@classes.dex
system@framework@svc.jar@classes.dex, File name too long
```

Вопрос что это? Как избавится от этого? Прочитал что это специальное ограничение. Никогда с таким не сталкивался

Comment: Обе fs, yaffs2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена.

я не описал, но я в коде использовал такую вещь как

```
IFS=$'\x9' #tab здесь проблема
set -- `busybox du -shm $FS`
```

После смены IFS, цикл for начел не правильно работать, место того чтобы использовать \n он ls использовал как \t. Чтобы это исправить я сделал так `DUMPIFS=$IFS` и после нужного действия так `IFS=$DUMPIFS`